# CURL Rest POST endpoint without requestbody

Tags: rest, curl, post, get

Is there any simple way of curl a REST API POST endpoint without a request body?
For some reason, the API i am working with is using a endpoint as POST even though its an obvious GET. No Request or HTTP parameters should be added to the request.

The response i get when i do: 
`curl -i -X POST https://APIURL 
is:
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add content-length header with your curl request as it is forcing to provide it with request.

```
-H "Content-Length: 0"
```